# Compare tabledatas and add CSS if the tabledata is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML-table with several tablerows. Each row contains 2 tabledata elements.
These td elements are filled with numbers.

I need code that helps me compare the numbers of each row and add CSS.
An example:

```
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

We are always going to use CSS on the second tabledata element. **If the value of the second td is lesser than the value of the first td element, it has to appear in *red* color**.
On the other hand, **if the value of the second td element is greater than the value of the first td element it has to appear in *green* color**.

This means that the tables contents should look something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td style='color:green;'>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td style='color:red;'>1</td>
</tr>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to get the inner values of each `td` element, compare the values and apply a style given the output. This assumes you always have two `td` elements. Any more and you would have to loop each `td` in the row and keep a running count.

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
   var firstTd = $(this).children(":first");
   var secondTd = $(this).children(":last");

   if (secondTd.html() < firstTd.html()) {
       secondTd.css("background-color", "red");
   } else if (secondTd.html() > firstTd.html()) {
       secondTd.css("background-color", "green");
   }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sru2bf59/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the your help! In fact my tablerows contain 4 td elements each. So im comparing the 2nd td element with the third while applying the CSS code to the third - I changed the code to this:

`$('table tr.SummaryContentTr').each(function(){
    var secondTd = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)');
    var thirdTd = $(this).children(':nth-child(3)');

    if (thirdTd.html() < secondTd.html())
 {
 thirdTd.css('color', 'red');
 } 
 else if (thirdTd.html() > secondTd.html())
 {
 thirdTd.css('color', 'green');
 }
    }); 
`
But now all the tds (3. child) are being set to green. Any clues?

Comment: Can you put it into a JSFiddle and post that as an update to your question?

Comment: I just copied the code to a new fiddle project. In fiddle the code is working. So I figured that the problem isn't the script, it's because the tablerows are created dynamically using PHP and a database.
I will have to fix that somehow. Your code works perfectly fine, thumbs up!

Comment: You can fix that by having it as a function that is called sometime after `document.ready` when the table has been created.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this function: [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgv8jxu0/)

This solution is without using JQuery of course.

Just in case, I also post the code here:

```
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <table>
           <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    <script>
      function myFunction(){
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++){
            if (i>=1 && i%2 != 0){
                if (parseInt(tds[i].innerText) > parseInt(tds[i-1].innerText)) {
                    tds[i].style.color = "green";
                } else {
                    tds[i].style.color = "red";
                }
            }
        }
      }
    </script>
```